# Passing JSON Body to a REST call in java

Tags: java, json, rest, post, httpclient

I am having trouble in executing a post call from java. However I am able to execute the same from Postman.
For my rest call content body should be like this

```
{"group": "group1","users": ["Z123456","a123456","x123456"]}
```

For this I created a pojo like this:

```
public class GroupUserMapping {
    String group;
    ArrayList<String> users;
}
```

And In code I created a method to add objects to this pojo like this

```
 ArrayList<GroupUserMapping> usergroups = new ArrayList<>();
//some conditions
 GroupUserMapping groupUserMapping = new GroupUserMapping(group,users);
  usergroups.add(groupUserMapping);
```

Now for all this objects I need to call the rest API

```
usergroups.stream().parallel().forEach(ausergroup -> {
    try {
       CloseableHttpClient client = HttpClients.createDefault();
       HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
       Gson gson = new Gson();
       String base64 = basicEncode();
       httpPost.addHeader("Authorization", base64);
       httpPost.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
       StringEntity entity = new StringEntity(gson.toJson(ausergroup.toString()));

       httpPost.setEntity(entity);
       HttpResponse response = client.execute(httpPost);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

});
```

after executing this I am getting 400 error code. Please help me in solving this?

Thank you.

Comment: Are you sure you use `ausergroup.toString()`?

Comment: yes. I am using ausergroup.toString()

Comment: Did you override the `toString` method of `GroupUserMapping`? Why do you use the `toString()` method?

Comment: As far as I can see in [Gson doc API](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/com.google.code.gson/gson/latest/com.google.gson/com/google/gson/Gson.html) you should be able to pass `ausergroup` without calling .toString()

Comment: yes. it worked when i remove tostring method. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed ausergroup.toString() to ausergroup. IT worked fine for me. However I have a new problem now.
When I am adding elements to pojo every time the group is adding as new element but users list is updating for all groups. Ideally it should be different for each group but after adding all elements I am seeing users are same for all groups. Where I am doing wrong?

Comment: You are using parallel stream but not using a synchronized list. Try to wrap your list in `Collections.synchronizedList()`